# Data Import Wizard not updating field

Tags: data, import, dataloader.io, data-import-wizard

Have had this issue a few times and not sure what's going on.

Using the Data Import Wizard fields just won't update. Most recently, wanted to update a custom field on Account. Uploaded a csv with Account ID and the field to update (numeric, custom field; pretty standard). Everything mapped. Uploaded with no error, yet the values for the field just did not change/update.

Have searched the forums, but still no clue what could be causing this as I can't find anyone else who's reporting this problem.

Used dataloader.io and it updated the field just fine, so no huge issue, just bugging me what could possibly be causing this.

Comment: Could be hitting a validation rule out asked error not causing it to commit the change. Try using the debug log.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you update your account make sure to click the box `update existing account information` and that should do the trick!